# Ascending order of log and power numbers

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

Put the following numbers in ascending order:
$$\log_{2}{3}$$
$$\sqrt{e}$$
$$(\sqrt{2})^2$$
$$2^{\sqrt{2}}$$

My success so far (in ascending order):
$$(\sqrt{2})^2 = \log_{2}{1}$$
$$2^\sqrt{2} = \log_{2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\log_{2}{3}$$

**UPD:** I messed up with exp to log transitions. Besides, it seems that the chosen approach (to make all functions to log) was wrong.

Please don't just give an answer but explain. And don't recommend calculator or super-advanced formulas solution.

Comment: There's a problem with your second identity, note that 

$$
\log_2\sqrt{2} = \log_2 2^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\log_2 2}_{=1} = \frac{1}{2} \not= 2^{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Also, $\log_2(1) = 0$, because $2^x = 1$ is satisfied when $x = 0$...

Comment: @Dair, oh. I see. I messed up with exponentials to logs transformations quite a bit :(

Comment: @caverac, I think that my chosen approach of making all functions to log is wrong then.

Comment: I tried putting everything in the form $2^{\rm something}$ but it doesn't help a lot either, sorry

Comment: @caverac, no problem. Thanks. I guess I can't solve it without calculator then (wanted to try to find easier solution first)

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of "your success" are wrong.  $\log_2 1=0$, but $(\sqrt 2)^2=2$, so $\log_2 (\sqrt2^2)=1$.  $\log_2(2^{\sqrt 2})=\sqrt 2$, not the other way around.  Since $\log_2$ is monotonic you can sort numbers by their base $2$ logs, but I don't think that is useful for the numbers you are given.

I would start with $(\sqrt 2)^2=2, 2^{\sqrt 2} \gt 2$, then note that $\log_2 3 \lt \log_2 4 = 2$, so $\log_2 3$ is first so far.  Also $\sqrt e \lt \sqrt 4=2$ so we are down to comparing $\log_2 3$ and $\sqrt e$.  My first thought is that $e \gt 2.56,$ so $\sqrt e \gt 1.6$.  It is true that $\log_2 3 \lt 1.6$ but I don't have an easy way to show that.